# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe produce unexpected behavior in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, release

I built a complete Xamarin From application. When I change build mode to `Release` I get this error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder::Append(System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32)'
>   in assembly: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::CopyBlockUnaligned(System.Void*,System.Void*,System.UInt32)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference
>   reference)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference
>   reference)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() EClinicForDoctor.Android

After searching on the Internet, I find this [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error) which says:

The resolution to this issue is to make sure you have the latest supported Android SDK versions, and set the Target Framework to Use latest installed platform. It's also recommended that you set the Target Android Version to Use Target Framework Version and the minimum Android version to API 15 or higher. This is considered the supported configuration.

Thus I update Android SDKs, set Target Framework and set minimum Android version to API 15.

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I still get the same error. Another solution says that I should update **NuGet Packages**. I found that the version of the package `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` is 4.3.0 and there is an update for this package. When updating the package, the error no longer appear but another problem occur. When the app deployed, it run and stop without any error message. The mobile just exit from application without showing any error message. This happens when the package `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` is on version higher than 4.3.0. I tried to remove the package and the same problem happens again. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get the solution. One of the comments in the [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1196) provided by @Gerald Versluis solve the problem:

> I follow these steps of hongliyu2002
>   https://forums.realm.io/t/could-not-load-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe-during-startup-registration/974/4
>
> 1. Go to C:\Users%user%.nuget\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.4.0, and
>      delete "ref" folder then make a copy of "lib" folder and rename the
>      copy back to "ref".
> 2. Cleanup all the "bin" and "obj" folders in the projects.
> 3. Rebuild and run..
>
> This simple workaround , works for me :) My current version is
>   Xamarin.Forms 2.5.1.444934

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this issue popup at a few different locations now. There is some discussion going around it like here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1196

This Github issue also lists some (possible) solutions, the one with the most positive feedback seems to be this one:

> Here's a functioning workaround. It's hacky and ugly but works with
>   minimum fuss. Put this in an XML file and `<Import>` it in your Android
>   csproj file at the end. It works at least for System.Buffers

```
<!-- Workaround for https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1162 -->
<Project>
  <Target Name="ReplaceRefAssemblies" AfterTargets="_ResolveAssemblies">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows Include="@(ResolvedAssemblies->Replace('\ref\','\lib\'))" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix Include="@(ResolvedAssemblies->Replace('/ref/','/lib/'))" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixed Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows)" Condition="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows) != @(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixed Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix)" Condition="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix) != @(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssemblies Remove="@(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssemblies Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixed)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Another uses the XML from above and says:

> 1. I've just copied the content from the link above and saved as `UnsafeFix.xml` file in the Android project folder.
> 2. Then just added: `<Import Project="UnsafeFix.xml" />` at the end of android .csproj file, just before
> 3. Cleared everything, recompiled and it finally worked!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the solution doesn't work. It give a list of errors that says: `The file "obj\Release\linksrc\....dll" does not exist.`

Comment: I give your +1 for your answer because the link actually contain the solution. Thanks :)